# Ubuntu (ZorinOS) boots only into tty1 terminal after delering all default keyrings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, terminal, grub

I am attempting to boot my computer after utilizing Seahorse to remove all of the default keyrings. Regretfully, the only thing I receive in return is a terminal that appears only on my secondary screen when my primary screen is off.

I already tried simply readding a default keyring using Python, but this doesn't work. Uninstallibg all drivers and autoinstalling also failed.

I believe I may have also taken out the keyring(s) for (a) startup command(s), which line up my secondary touchscreen's touch input and output. Consequently, the startup commands are now stuck and cannot be executed at all.

I also fail to enter grub on startup and fail to resolve any packages from archive.ubuntu.com

[startup output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQYgV.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.